# Can't install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 package (fatal error)

Tags: installation

I am trying to run the Elder Scrolls Online Launcher installer, it loads to 100% and then just quits.  I have a feeling it has to do with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 not being able to install.  Here is the log file for the error installing Visual c++.  What would be causing this issue? I have tried clearing permissions and various other things to no avail.

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N68mN.png)

Comment: can you make available the msi log file referenced in the error?

Comment: @emk how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Can you find the log file that starts "Microsoft Visual C++... It maybe in %temp% or %windir%\temp. After finding it, maybe use Pastebin to share it. Everything search tool -  https://www.voidtools.com might help you find it.